# Low Frame Rate Problem in MVSDK Python Demos

Tags: python, camera, buffer, frame-rate, ethernet

The demos that are offered in the ethernet cameras with MVSDK library in Python have a frame rate of only 10 FPS , when in the GTK demo it shows me a frame rate of 80 FPS with the same exposure level and resolution both in the demos and in my application. After investigating the code in the demo file cv_grab.py, it seems that the problem is related to the specific function call: `mvsdk.CameraGetImageBuffer(hCamera, 200)`. I think appears to be some bottleneck or problem in the way the image is accessed or processed within the buffer, resulting in the lower than desired frame rate. Could someone please provide me with guidance or solutions to increase the frame rate for real-time video display in python?

I have reviewed the MVSDK documentation, but have not found detailed information on how to specifically address this problem. I have also tried experimenting with different timeout values in the call to CameraGetImageBuffer and increasing the buffer size, but I have not been able to get a higher frame rate in python.